Div not showing with JavaScript
I'm currently improving my website for the use with mobile devices. Therefore I'm trying to open a menu with a click onto a equiv button. The menu is a fixed div with scrollable content and should appear and disappear with a click onto the button. Either option is working if set through the display property in CSS, but I'm not able to toggle the visibility through JavaScript.


function ToggleDiv() {
  var v = document.getElementById('equiv-submenu');

  if (v.style.display == '' || v.style.display == 'none') {
    v.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    v.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
<div id="equiv" onclick="ToggleDiv()">
  <p>&equiv;</p>
</div>

<div id="equiv-submenu">
  <div id="equiv-submenu-content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>




This question is similar to: How to toggle  show and hide with JS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I cannot see any element with id = "equiv-submenu".

I've added the missing div.

This is why it's always a good idea to start a question with a small reproducible example (preferably a runnable snippet), here your snippet works fine on mobile.   I'm currently flagging as not reproducible.

That's the part that confuses me. If I set 'display' to none the div  is not visible, but if I set it to block it is. May something block the execution of the script? If I change the code to an alert function it is executed without any problems.

The equiv-submenu is embedded into other divs of the page, but I set the position to fixed. Could that be a possible reason for the script to not execute?

Check the computed style to handle the case where display is set in CSS
function ToggleDiv() {
    var v = document.getElementById('equiv-submenu');

    if (window.getComputedStyle(v).display === 'none') {
        v.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        v.style.display = 'none';
    }
}


Unfortunately, the results are the same.

@Kirneh Share the CSS code with me, and I can help you review it to check for any potential issues

You can solve your problem by replacing the code below with your javascript code:
document.getElementById('equiv').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var v = document.getElementById('equiv-submenu');
    v.style.display = (v.style.display === 'none' || v.style.display === '') ? 'block' : 'none';
});


This is the solution to your problem. Also, compared to your previous code, this code is more take up less space.

The code is just a shorter version of the answer above and doesn't solve the problem either.

@Kirneh How come the code that works for me doesn't work for you?

@rozsazoltan Thanks for your answer, but I did it like this to make the code shorter. You can also put it in the if block if you wish.

Using getComputedStyle allows you to see the final CSS values applied to an element, even if they were changed by JavaScript or other styles.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle


function ToggleDiv() {
  var v = document.getElementById('equiv-submenu');

  var style = getComputedStyle(v);

  if (style.display == '' || style.display == 'none') {
    v.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    v.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
<div id="equiv" onclick="ToggleDiv()">
  <p>&equiv;</p>
</div>

<div id="equiv-submenu">
  <div id="equiv-submenu-content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>




function ToggleDiv() {
    var v = document.getElementById('equiv-submenu');
    
    if (v.style.display === 'none' || v.style.display === '') {
        v.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        v.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

// Add event listener to the button
document.getElementById('equiv').addEventListener('click', ToggleDiv);

<div id="equiv">
    <p>&equiv;</p>
</div>

<div id="equiv-submenu" style="display: none;">
    <!-- Your menu content here -->
</div>

Ensure that your equiv-submenu div has an initial display: none style, either inline or in your CSS

I've tried both options, adding the 'display' property inline and in css, both didn't work. The EventListener didn't succeeded too...
